# GolangでWebsocketでReceiveで一定時間を経過したらデータを送る

Tags: go, websocket

Golangでwebsocketを使って、

ある一定時間だけReceiveし、もし、その間になんらかのデータが送られてきたらそのデータについて処理するが、その時間内に何も来なかったら、こちらからデータを送る方法はありますか?

下の例だとずっとReceiveで送られてくるのを待ち続けてしまいます。どうすればいいのでしょうか?

一定時間(例えば5秒間)Receiveする -> もし、その間にデータが送られてきたら -> そのデータを処理する。送られて来なければ、こちらからデータを送る

ということがしたいです。

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "golang.org/x/net/websocket"
    "io/ioutil"
    "net/http"
    "os"
)

func picHandler(ws *websocket.Conn) {
    websocket.Message.Receive(ws, &s) 
    // なんらかの処理

    // もし、一定時間過ぎたなら
        websocket.Message.Send(ws, pic)
}

func main() {
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Fprintln(os.Stderr, err)
    }
    http.HandleFunc("/pic", func(w http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request) {
        s := websocket.Server{Handler: websocket.Handler(picHandler)}
        s.ServeHTTP(w, req)

    })
    fmt.Println("port:", 9563)
    http.ListenAndServe(":9563", nil)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SetReadDeadline`を使うことで、
指定時間までに受信できなかった場合にタイムアウトエラーを発生させることができます。

```
func picHandler(ws *websocket.Conn) {
    var s, pic string

    // 5秒後にタイムアウト
    ws.SetReadDeadline(time.Now().Add(time.Second * 5))

    err := websocket.Message.Receive(ws, &s)

    // タイムアウトが発生したかチェック
    if operr, ok := err.(*net.OpError); ok && operr.Timeout() {
        websocket.Message.Send(ws, pic)
    }
}
```